# Allow scroll but hide scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` with element styles like this:

```
 <div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;">< id="DivTableContainer" ></div>
```

I need to allow scrolling along the y-axis when it becomes higher than 300px, this works fine. But I need to set `"visiblity = false"` to scroll bar itself.

I tried to use this element style:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

While it hides the scroll bar, it also disallows scrolling. Is there a way to get scrolling without having the scrollbar visible?

Comment: Try [nanoScroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/), it shows the scroll bar when you hover.

Comment: Hi @Jake745. I edited your question, because it was not comprehensible before. Can you please check that it still asks what you wanted to ask? If not, please leave a comment or edit it yourself :).

Comment: Good work Jonas. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's better, if you use two div containers in HTML .

As Shown Below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="container2">
        // Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 #container2{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/540144

Answer (score 31):

I know this is an oldie but here is a quick way to hide the scroll bar with pure CSS.

Just add

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

To your id or class of the div you're using the scroll bar with.

Here is a helpful link [Custom Scroll Bar in Webkit](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Comment: doesnt work on Firefox though ;)

Comment: correct, Firefox doesn't have ::webkit .. you would have to use some javascript or jquery to hide it or try using some css to style it.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        // Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8QzmH/)**

Tested on FF and Safari.

Comment: Good idea imbondbaby.

Comment: -1... So you are going to accept the answer, then unaccept it?